# Where to edit (which part of the document ) a LAMP servers host file? [and correct synax]

Tags: apache, localhost, web-hosting, lamp

While trying to edit a host file on a ubuntu server, the docs recommend updating the system's host file saying

> The hosts file creates static associations between IP addresses and
>   hostnames or domains which the system prioritizes before DNS for name
>   resolution. Open this file in a text editor and add a line for your
>   Linode’s public IP address. You can associate this address with your
>   Linode’s Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) if you have one, and with
>   the local hostname you set in the steps above. In the example below,
>   203.0.113.10 is the public IP address, example-hostname is the local hostname, and example-hostname.example.com is the FQDN.

After opening a SSH connection and running

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

The host file can now be edited. After scrolling to the bottom of the page to add the new lines I looked back at the example in the documentation:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
203.0.113.10 example-hostname.example.com example-hostname
```

Is this the correct format?

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
104.123.155.24 newhostuser.104.123.155.24 newhostuser
```

Comment: The hosts file is `/etc/hosts`. It isn't called `apache2.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add HostName entry in `/etc/hosts` file. If you want to run Apache on IP address then you can edit `Listen` entry in apache2.conf file.

Comment: Thank you. Is my example above correct? I'm especially curious if my example was correct for the value `example-hostname.example.com`

Comment: Yes. `IP address  hostname [hostalias]...` is the format of /etc/hosts file.